# split rows in the 4th column of a table with comma

Tags: javascript

My code to get data from the 4th column of my table.

```
function getColumn(table_id, col) {
var tab = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[4];
var n = tab.rows.length;
var i, s = null, tr, td;
if (col < 0) {
    return null;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tr = tab.rows[i];
    if (tr.cells.length > col) { // Check that cell exists before you try
        td = tr.cells[col];      // to access it.
        s += ' ' + td.innerText;
    }
} return s; }
var txt = getColumn('partTable', 4);
```

It is returning

> "Jeans A Shirt B Pant T"

I would like it to return

> "Jeans A, Shirt B, Pant T"

How is this possible in my code? I do not want to replace the space with ", " since i sometime would have spaces in the number

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try replacinig space (" ") with comma and space (, ).

Comment: this wont work as sometime i would have spaces in the numbers.

Comment: In that case Use regular expression  to replace all spaces by comma and space. The regular expression for multiple spaces is \s*

Comment: I cant do that, if one of my value is "10 98", i do not want to split this by comma as this is not 2 numbers.

Comment: @Mojo Rakesh his suggestion doesn't break the numbers into two.

Comment: i have updated the code to make it a bit more clear, if you look at the code i am trying to split my products with a ","

Comment: I think Rakesh ment to do something like: `s += td.innerText + ', ';` instead of `s += ' ' + td.innerText`

Comment: but then if i have a comma in the product name, it wont work?